# sfGuard token login for wkhtmltopdf

Tags: security, symfony-1.4, wkhtmltopdf, sfguard

[wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) allows to make a screenshot of a browser view with a webkit browser.

I have a Symfony 1.4 application that requires login, which I would like to use wkhtmltopdf to create a "print this page" function.

How can I securely facilitate this. I'm thinking of creating a one-off token on each screen for the print button that allows wkhtmltopdf to login without using the password of the user.

Any suggestions for how to structure this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'vbe come to the conclusion to use the built in "keep me logged in" functionality for this problem.

Comment: Im facing the exact same problem! How did you solve it by using "keep me logged in"? I tried but it still prints the "authentication page" pdf instead of the current page.

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider a different printing framework ? 
What about jquery plugin (e.g. https://github.com/ianoxley/jqueryprintpage#readme) ? 
That way you won't have to allow access to the restricted area from outside the session.

If you still want to use [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/), you can easily create an action that receives a url and a user_id and creates a unique token, I might save this token in your DB or in a Key-Value cache (depends what is your system architecture). I wouldn't create the unique token in advance, I think its better creating it on demand (When your user is asking a print).

You have couple of options in order to enable printing in secured actions,

1) Create a custom security filter. In the filter, in addition to authenticated request, you have to allow requests that contain "token" parameter with right combination of url and user

2) Change the action to unsecured. If you don't want the change the security filter, you would have to change each action to "unsecured" and create a function that verifies if either the request is authenticated or it has a proper token parameter.

It would be smart to remove each token after you used it once to make it even harder to guess a token.

In addition you might want to create a periodic worker that clears old tokens that were never in use.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you already decided on an approach, I would still like to add one more alternate option that might help others viewing this issue.

Another alternate route might be to grab the current source of the page being viewed and post that into your printer backend using something like

```
$.post("/printer", document.documentElement.outerHTML);
```

This way you can also preprocess the HTML in an easy way. Your backed could first store the HTML and then parse it to for example convert images or perhaps remove some parts of the page that will not be used when printing.